# Connectivity to AWS EKS control plane via Client VPN

Tags: amazon-eks

I have created EKS cluster with API server endpoint access as "Private". Cluster is configured in private subnet. I'd like to allow kubectl access from local PC. I have created Client VPN, it has access to private network (verified that by SSH to an EC2 instance running in the same private subnet). But  kubectl gets "unable to connect to the server: dial x.x.x.x:443 i/o timout". "aws eks update-kubeconfig" can see that cluster and updates local context properly. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was was missing. 443 had to be enabled in authorization rules

Comment: hey im having the same problem, but i dont understand your answer where have you enabled port 443 ? can you show an image if possible?